# How to re-sort JSON file based on value inside object Java Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to parse and read a JSON file I get. I get an "appointmentInstance" in every object, and I would like to re-sort the whole file based on the appointmentInstance. Example:
If the JSONFile appointmentInstance has this sort of structure:

```
{
response: {
status: 200,
message: "",
details: "",
eventId: 0,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 9,
totalRows: 9,
data: [
{
id: 509955,
startTimeSlot: 5,
appointmentInstance: 310051
},
{
id: 509961,
startTimeSlot: 2,
appointmentInstance: 310057
},
{
id: 510070,
startTimeSlot: 3,
appointmentInstance: 310166
},
{
id: 510074,
startTimeSlot: 4,
appointmentInstance: 310170
},
{
id: 510522,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310419
},
{
id: 510523,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310420
},
{
id: 510524,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310421
},
{
id: 510525,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310060
},
{
id: 510535,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310171
}
]
}
}
```

Then I would like it to be re-sorted to:

```
{
response: {
status: 200,
message: "",
details: "",
eventId: 0,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 9,
totalRows: 9,
data: [
{
id: 509955,
startTimeSlot: 5,
appointmentInstance: 310051
},
{
id: 509961,
startTimeSlot: 2,
appointmentInstance: 310057
},
{
id: 510525,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310060
},
{
id: 510070,
startTimeSlot: 3,
appointmentInstance: 310166
},
{
id: 510074,
startTimeSlot: 4,
appointmentInstance: 310170
},
{
id: 510535,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310171
}
{
id: 510522,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310419
},
{
id: 510523,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310420
},
{
id: 510524,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310421
},
]
}
}
```

How can I do so? With my current code, I am able to "print out" the appointmentInstance, but it would of course not be printed in order.

My JSON:

```
{
response: {
status: 200,
message: "",
details: "",
eventId: 0,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 9,
totalRows: 9,
data: [
{
id: 509955,
startTimeSlot: 5,
appointmentInstance: 310051
},
{
id: 509961,
startTimeSlot: 2,
appointmentInstance: 310057
},
{
id: 510070,
startTimeSlot: 3,
appointmentInstance: 310166
},
{
id: 510074,
startTimeSlot: 4,
appointmentInstance: 310170
},
{
id: 510522,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310419
},
{
id: 510523,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310420
},
{
id: 510524,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310421
},
{
id: 510525,
startTimeSlot: 6,
appointmentInstance: 310060
},
{
id: 510535,
startTimeSlot: 7,
appointmentInstance: 310171
}
]
}
}
```

My Java Android code:

```
try {
        String thatarray = "{response: {status: 200,message: "",details: "",eventId: 0,startRow: 0,endRow: 9,totalRows: 9,data: [{id: 509955,startTimeSlot: 5,appointmentInstance: 310051},{id: 509961,startTimeSlot: 2,appointmentInstance: 310057},{id: 510070,startTimeSlot: 3,appointmentInstance: 310166},{id: 510074,startTimeSlot: 4,appointmentInstance: 310170},{id: 510522,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310419},{id: 510523,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310420},{id: 510524,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310421},{id: 510525,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310060},{id: 510535,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310171}]}}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(thatarray);
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for(int i = jsonArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("appointmentInstance"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: create a List, add [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)s, Override the compareTo() method, sort the List, have them ordered.

Comment: This appears to be an school project, because of that, I have not added code to an answer. So, I gave you guidelines on how to attemp to resolve it... `List` is a Class in Java, that can hold `Object` refferences., there is a `sort()` method, that calls `Object.compareTo(Object)` method, this way, you can google how to do this simply. And have an ordered list with your Objects

Comment: @Bonatti it's not a school project :P, although it indeed looked like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding it to int[] appointments

Answer (score 1):

Use a List with Collection.sort() method like this

```
List<Integer> appointments = new ArrayList<Integer>();

try {
    String thatarray = "{response: {status: 200,message: "",details: "",eventId: 0,startRow: 0,endRow: 9,totalRows: 9,data: [{id: 509955,startTimeSlot: 5,appointmentInstance: 310051},{id: 509961,startTimeSlot: 2,appointmentInstance: 310057},{id: 510070,startTimeSlot: 3,appointmentInstance: 310166},{id: 510074,startTimeSlot: 4,appointmentInstance: 310170},{id: 510522,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310419},{id: 510523,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310420},{id: 510524,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310421},{id: 510525,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310060},{id: 510535,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310171}]}}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(thatarray);
    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i = jsonArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        appointments.add(jsonObject.getInt("appointmentInstance"));
    }
    Collections.sort(appointments);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: It's great, but I would also like to have the "id" and "timeslot" (as you see in my json) to be accesible

Comment: If you need more variable then you will wrap them in a class and use a  Comparator to sort it based on the class variable you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

First Create model of your JSON response:

```
 public class ResponseModel {
        private int id;
        private int startTimeSlot;
        private int appointmentInstance;

      public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

 public void setstartTimeSlot(int startTimeSlot) {
        this.startTimeSlot= startTimeSlot;
    }

    public int getstartTimeSlot() {
        return startTimeSlot
    }

    public void setappointmentInstance(int appointmentInstance){
        this.appointmentInstance= appointmentInstance;
    }

    public int getappointmentInstance(){
        return appointmentInstance;
    }


    }
```

And:

```
try {
        // create a list:
        private ArrayList<ResponseModel> myList = new ArrayList<ResponseModel>();
        String thatarray = "{response: {status: 200,message: "",details: "",eventId: 0,startRow: 0,endRow: 9,totalRows: 9,data: [{id: 509955,startTimeSlot: 5,appointmentInstance: 310051},{id: 509961,startTimeSlot: 2,appointmentInstance: 310057},{id: 510070,startTimeSlot: 3,appointmentInstance: 310166},{id: 510074,startTimeSlot: 4,appointmentInstance: 310170},{id: 510522,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310419},{id: 510523,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310420},{id: 510524,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310421},{id: 510525,startTimeSlot: 6,appointmentInstance: 310060},{id: 510535,startTimeSlot: 7,appointmentInstance: 310171}]}}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(thatarray);
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for(int i = jsonArray.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
            responseModel.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
            responseModel.setstartTimeSlot(jsonObject.getInt("startTimeSlot"));
            responseModel.setappointmentInstance(jsonObject.getInt("appointmentInstance"));            
            myList.add(responseModel);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    //Sorting:

Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<ResponseModel >() {
                public int compare(ResponseModel o1, ResponseModel o2) {
                return (o1.getappointmentInstance - o2.getappointmentInstance);
                        }
                });
```

Now you have sorted list  (myList) by appointmentInstance.

Comment: @Jason, I edited my answer. In your case you can compare numbers inside compare method without compareTo.